# cannot scroll to botttom on button toggle in ionic 3

Tags: ionic3

[image]

Hi have a button in the list-item like above. On this click, I'm showing the list-items below this item. I have added code to scroll to bottom as soon as the advanced button is opened to show items below, but it does not seems to work.

```
<ion-content>
.
.
.
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-row text-center>
            <ion-col>
              <button
              ion-button
              block icon-end
              (click)="toggleAccordion()"
                  >Advanced Search
                  <ion-icon name="arrow-down" [ngClass]="{'active': booleanAccordion}" ></ion-icon>
              </button>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
<ion-list *ngIf="booleanAccordion">
    <ion-item>
        <from-to-filter headerText="Table %"></from-to-filter>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
<ion-list *ngIf="booleanAccordion">
    <ion-item>
        <from-to-filter headerText="Depth %"></from-to-filter>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

```
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';
@Component({
selector: 'page-search',
templateUrl: 'search.html',
})
export class SearchPage {
@ViewChild(Content) content: Content;
----
toggleAccordion() {
this.booleanAccordion = !this.booleanAccordion;
this.content.scrollToBottom();
}
---
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, Ionic events get lost in the event loop schedule. The simplest way to go through is to use setTimeout (even if it's a bit ugly). Try this :

```
toggleAccordion() {
   this.booleanAccordion = !this.booleanAccordion;
   setTimeout(() => this.content.scrollToBottom(), 100);
}
```

You could also use ngZone but it would be a bit overkill here.

Comment: tried but it is not scrolling...to the last item in the list

Comment: there was some issue in my page, I sorted it, and now its working like charm thanks